# ArmstrongNumber checker

Tags: java, algorithm, strings, integer

This is my code written to check whether a given number is armstrong or not . but the logic differs from the conventional logic of using integer and separating its digits and calculating , instead i optimize the logic of separating the digits using Sting and char array . Please review my code ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ArmstrongNumberChecker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number;
        int sum = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            System.out.println("\nEnter the number to check if it is armstrong number\n");
            number = scanner.nextInt();
            String s = Integer.toString(number);
            char[] c = s.toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                sum = ( int ) (sum + Math.pow((c[i] - 48), c.length));
            }
            if (sum == number) {
                System.out.println("Number " + number + " is Armstrong");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Number " + number + " is not Armstrong");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid data");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview! Can you provide a link or a definition of what Armstrong means?

Comment: Ya sure Austin, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I rolled back your last edit. After getting an answer you are [not allowed to change your code anymore](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). This is to ensure that answers do not get invalidated and have to hit a moving target. If you have changed your code you can either post it as an answer (if it would constitute a code review) or ask a new question with your changed code (linking back to this one as reference). Refer to [this post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765/120114) for more information

Comment: Now what can I do,  I am new to code review.

Comment: Thanks to edit my question to previous, @Sᴀᴍ Onᴇᴌᴀ .

Answer (score 3):

It's one big static main method that works only on data from System.in. Start by refactoring the algorithm into a reusable utility method that works with integers. You're working with numbers so requiring the input to be a string is not an improvement (it seems like a cop-out to make the coding easier for you).

An armstrong number can not be larger than 4 * 9^3 so you should add range checks to avoid useless checking.

You're not prepared for negative values.

You catch generic Exception, ignore it and report a pretty useless error message. You know what the possible exceptions are (IOException and NumberFormatException), so catch them and tell the user exactly what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reviews everyone. Using the ideas in answer  I rewrote my code.

Here I changed my void main () and use it to only call my methods to run the program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ArmstrongNumberChecker().mainMethod();
    }
```

I also separated the tasks by creating methods in my class and handled exceptions in the method .

```
private void mainMethod() {
        try {
            System.out.println("\nEnter the number to check if it is armstrong number\n");
            number = scanner.nextInt();
            armstrongChecker();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println(e + "\t : Only integers allowed");
        }
    }

    private void armstrongChecker() {
        String s = Integer.toString(number);
        char[] c = s.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            sum = ( int ) (sum + Math.pow((c[i] - 48), c.length));
        }
        if (sum == number) {
            System.out.println("Number " + number + " is Armstrong");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Number " + number + " is not Armstrong");
        }
    }
```

Putting it all together my code looks like this.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArmstrongNumberChecker {
    private int number;
    private int sum = 0;
    private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ArmstrongNumberChecker().mainMethod();
    }

    private void mainMethod() {
        try {
            System.out.println("\nEnter the number to check if it is armstrong number\n");
            number = scanner.nextInt();
            armstrongChecker();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println(e + "\t : Only integers allowed");
        }
    }

    private void armstrongChecker() {
        String s = Integer.toString(number);
        char[] c = s.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            sum = ( int ) (sum + Math.pow((c[i] - 48), c.length));
        }
        if (sum == number) {
            System.out.println("Number " + number + " is Armstrong");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Number " + number + " is not Armstrong");
        }
    }
}
```